# Why am i getting ANR(Application Not Responding) on paginated recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, pagination, android-anr-dialog

In my application i'm basically trying to paginate my recycler view where firstly my recycler view is loaded with 50 items, then after i add 50 more items to recycler view. On page change everything is working fine, however the crucial part is that when page is changed my application goes into ANR state. To fix this i also tried putting my code into AsyncTask class but still nothing seemed to help. Please take a look at my code and help me resolve the problem. Any help will be appreciated.!

This is the code of my activity class:

Here is the `onScrollListener` code registered in activity;

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(mActivity, 3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
rcv_images.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(3, 4, true));
rcv_images.setLayoutManager(manager);

mMainFolderImagesAdapter = new MainFolderImagesAdapter(mAlbumName, mDatabaseHelper, mActivity, bean);
mMainFolderImagesAdapter.setItemClickListener(MainFolderImagesActivity.this);
rcv_images.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new PaginationScrollListener(manager) {
    @Override
    protected void loadMoreItems() {

        isLoading = true;
        currentPage += 1;
        loadNextPage();

    }

    @Override
    public int getTotalPageCount() {
        return totalpage;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLastPage() {
        return isLastPage;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLoading() {
        return isLoading;
    }
});


rcv_images.setAdapter(mMainFolderImagesAdapter);
```

This is the load next page method which is loading next items into recycler view:

```
private void loadNextPage() {
        boolean islast1 = false;
        mMainFolderImagesAdapter.removeLoadingFooter();

        ArrayList<String> tempImages = new ArrayList<>();
        if (mMainFolderImagesAdapter.getItemCount() + 50 <= mImageItems.size()) {
            for (int i = mMainFolderImagesAdapter.getItemCount(); i < mMainFolderImagesAdapter.getItemCount() + 50; i++) {
                tempImages.add(mImageItems.get(i));
            }

            mMainFolderImagesAdapter.updateResult1(tempImages);
            changeCount(mImageItems.size());

            isLoading = false;

        } else {
            for (int i = mMainFolderImagesAdapter.getItemCount(); i < mImageItems.size(); i++) {
                tempImages.add(mImageItems.get(i));
            }

            mMainFolderImagesAdapter.updateResult1(tempImages);
            changeCount(mImageItems.size());


            isLoading = false;
            islast1 = true;

        }
        if (currentPage != totalpage) {
            mMainFolderImagesAdapter.addLoadingFooter();
        } else isLastPage = true;

        if (islast1) {
            mMainFolderImagesAdapter.setlast();
        }


    }

This is the method which i'm using in adapter to update my items:

 public void updateResult1(ArrayList<String> imageItems) {


        thumbPaths.addAll(imageItems);

        notifyItemRangeInserted(getItemCount(), thumbPaths.size());

    }
```

This is my recycler xml code format:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cl_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_images"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
             />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_images"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No Images"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Comment: For paging library it required view model architecture but i'm not using that in my application

Comment: not really, see [Understanding the Paging Library, PagedList](https://bloggie.io/@_junrong/part-1-understanding-the-paging-library-pagedlist)

Comment: Please also add the logs...

Comment: What kind of log you need? my app is not crashing

Comment: so why do you want to reinvent the wheel if you already have a working pagination library?

Comment: Well because i'm not experienced with that library and still i'm facing issues with that library